# jspdf output filename produce un error en angular

Tags: jspdf

Alguien econtró la solución a este error en angular

window.open( doc.output("bloburl",{filename:'prueba'}),'_blank' );

Answer (score 0):

Más que error, tu problema es que no estableces la propiedad de título adecuadamente. Esto puede solucionarlo:

```
doc.setProperties({
  title: "MyTitle.pdf"
});
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));
```